# Python: How to pass this chain of commands at once to subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to pass these below chained commands at once to the ***subprocess***.But it's throwing error.

Command to pass:

```
"C:\MyScript\run.bat" -I"C:\MyScript" -- "C:\MyScript\MyScript1.pl" "file_name"
```

where, file_name is a variable which holds the name of a file.

Code:

```
cmd = '"C:\MyScript\run.bat" -I"C:\MyScript" -- "C:\MyScript\MyScript1.pl"' + " " + filename
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Test\WWX_2.py", line 28, in
<module>
subprocess.call(cmd)
File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 444, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 821, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You don’t need to include the `" "` inside the `cmd` list btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use raw string literals to prevent `\r` from being interpreted as a carriage return. The space-only arguments are also passed as actual command line arguments, but you probably don't want that to happen, so remove them.

```
cmd = [r'C:\MyScript\run.bat', r'-I"C:\MyScript"', '--', r'C:\MyScript\MyScript1.pl', filename]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: I think getting the command in a list is not a good idea. After many attempts I was able to generate the correct command string using the below code:                                       `cmd = r'C:\MyScript\run.bat' + r' -I"C:\MyScript"' + ' --'+ r' C:\MyScript\MyScrip1.pl'+ " " + file_path` . But since you have enlightened me about the **raw string literals**, I'm accepting your answer as the correct one. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape all the backslashes in the path, i.e.

```
C:\\whatever\\batch.bat
```